# ObjectiveC passing class Pointer to static library and then calling methods from class

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Hello and thanks for any help in advance. I tried searching but it seems that what I am trying to do is no common. If there is another post talking about my question please link.

To get started, I have two classes. To keep names simple, one is called Controller and the other is my AppDelegate. The controller is a static library. The AppDelegate creates an instance of the controller using the following.

*Note: I have already declared _controller in .h file.

```
_controller  = [[Controller alloc] initWithAppDelegate:self];
```

What I would like to do, is call methods in the AppDelegate class from the controller. Relevant code in the controller.h class is as follows.

```
@interface
{
  id _appDelegate;
}

-(id) initWithAppDelegate:(id)appDelegate;
```

and in controller.m

```
-(void)someMethodName
{
  [_appDelegate method];
}
```

The issue I am having is that method is not available to be called. I can call several other methods but not the custom methods I have created within AppDelegate. I have tried replacing ID with the AppDelegate but I can't seem to be able to import AppDelegate, I somewhat understand why I can't import it.

The reason I am creating my project this way is that I would like to reuse the controller code in applications that have a UI designed for different devices. If any of this is unclear or you need more information, feel free to ask.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a protocol like this in your static library:

```
@protocol AppDelegateRequiredMethods
@required
... methods here ...
@end
```

Then, import the header that declares that protocol into your various AppDelegate implementations and declare your app delegate as implementing said protocol:

```
@interface MyAppDelegate:NSObject <AppDelegateRequiredMethods>
...
@end
```

Comment: Once you have your protocol you change your property / instance variable and init methods: `id < AppDelegateRequiredMethods > _appDelegate;`, `- (id)initWithAppDelegate:(id < AppDelegateRequiredMethods >)appDelegate;`

Comment: Awesome, I believe this will work. I will mark as answered once I have more time to implement.

Comment: @Wain, thanks for adding that extra info for clarity. This solution worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

The Controller has no knowledge of the app delegate or its methods. You must declare the interface using a protocol.

```
@protocol AppDelegateMethods
- (void)method;
@end

//Then replace your current id with     
id <AppDelegateMethods>
```

Comment: Using `id` as you've described adds fragility to the code because you've hamstrung the compiler's ability to ensure that the app delegate implements the methods.  The app delegate should be declared to conform to the protocol so the compiler can validate the implementation properly.

Comment: @bbum fixed it, even if it isnt called that, same idea

Comment: @bbum, that part refers to the controller code.. I fail to see the problem, in fact comments on your own answer suggest the same thing.

Comment: No, the comments do not imply the same thing.   What @wain suggested strongly types the `_appDelegate` itself, which is unrelated to applying the the protocol to the class declaration itself.  In your code, the compiler would not warn if the app delegate didn't implement a method.

Comment: @bbum That is what im suggesting in my answer as well. If you are referreing to `@required`  it is implicitly defaulted

Comment: Where did you suggest declaring the app delegate as conforming to the protocol?  I.e. `@interface AppDelegate:NSObject <AppDelegateProtocolFromLibrary>`?   Without that, the compiler can't vaildate the implementation in `AppDelegate.m`.  With it, it can.

Comment: @bbum I thought how a protocol is used is implied. This wasnt a question about how to use protocols. Even so the compiler would throw a warning if he didn't and tried to assign AppDelegate to id<AppDelegateMethods>.